# Peticion GET curl no devuelve datos JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, curl

Estoy usando una API (GET) CURL en un PHP mediante HTML+javascript  con el siguiente codigo

```
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cuerpo"></div>
</body>
<script>

ch = curl_init();
url='https://www.dominio.com/api/v2/projects/{PROJECT_TOKEN}/last_ready_run/data?{api_key}&format=JSON"'
      

       ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL,url);
       curl_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
       result=curl_exec(ch);
       
       console.log(ch);   //No muestra nada
       cuerpo.innerHTML=ch; //No muestra nada

</script>
```

Y obtengo la respuesta ok (200).-

[image: Y obtengo la respuesta ok (200).-]
Que me esta faltando para mostrar los datos?
Gracias!!

Comment: La respuesta de cURL estaría en `result`, no en `ch`. ¿Esto es Node.js o qué es esto? Pregunto porque cURL trabaja en el servidor y aquí veo que tienes tu código cURL en el código del cliente ¿?

Comment: Efectivamente, se que trabaja del lado del servidor, pero me devuelve error de conexion 443 el de los puertos con conexion SSL; fuen entonces cuando pense....hacer un  codigo html+jS metido en un .php; de esta forma es como estoy obteniendo la respuesta OK 200

Comment: ¿Y el problema cuál es concretamente? ¿Has hecho una prueba de `respuesta` mediante **`console.log(respuesta);`** que es donde estaría lo que te devuelve cURL?

Comment: Dejar tu token y api key a la vista de todos los clientes no suena bien; es como si te dieran la llave de una puerta y la colgaras por fuera.

Comment: Ya SAL, soy consciente que se deben proteger esos parametros, pero al hacer un var_dump a $result, muestra "false", y viendo el motivo me dice que rechaza la conexion (error 443), y eso ya no lo puedo controlar, depende del hosting donde tengo mi proyecto y del servidor de donde consumo la API.- (desde wamp si que funciona y va de maravilla, pero al subir al hosting no) por eso estoy buscando otras alternativas

Comment: Hecho!!, he pasado todo el CURL a PHP, incluso he copiado la API generada en POSTMAN, lo ejecuto en WAMP y perfecto, sin embargo lo subo a mi hosting, la peticion devuelve OK pero el volcado de datos da el mismo error 443 y no los muestra

Comment: Comparte el mensaje de error completo.

Answer (score 0):

Repasa tus manuales, no tienes claro dónde se ejecuta el javascript y dónde se ejecuta el php.

```
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cuerpo">
<?php
$url='https://www.dominio.com/api/v2/projects/{PROJECT_TOKEN}/last_ready_run/data?{api_key}&format=JSON"'
      
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
$result=curl_exec(ch);

echo $result;       
?>
</div>
</body>
```

La llamada la puedes hacer toda con PHP y volcar el resultado (echo) en el HTML que se generará. ¿Y el javascript? Nada no intervendría.

Otra opción es cargar la página y utilizar jquery para hacer una llamada tipo Ajax. El problema en este caso es que vas a dejar visible los valores de *PROJECT_TOKEN* y *api_key* como indica algún comentario, no es una buena práctica.

Comment: Hecho!!, he pasado todo el CURL a PHP, incluso he copiado la API generada en POSTMAN, lo ejecuto en WAMP y perfecto, sin embargo lo subo a mi hosting, la peticion devuelve OK pero el volcado de datos da el mismo error 443